Higher-Rank trait bounds with multiple generics
Suppose I the following rust code.
struct Source<'a> {
    content: &'a str,
}

struct Final<'a> {
    content: &'a str,
}

struct Intermediary<'a> {
    content: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> From<Intermediary<'a>> for Final<'a> {
    fn from(intermediary: Intermediary<'a>) -> Self {
        Final { content: intermediary.content }
    }
}

fn example<F, C>(f: F)
where
    for<'a> F: FnOnce(Source<'a>) -> C,
    for<'a> C: Into<Final<'a>>,{
    // implementation details
}

fn call() {
    example(|source| {
        Intermediary { content: source.content }
    });
}

This doesn't compile with the error message:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:51:9
   |
50 |     example(|source| {
   |              ------- return type of closure is Intermediary<'2>
   |              |
   |              has type `Source<'1>`
51 |         Intermediary { content: source.content }
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

I think the problem is that the for<'a> for F and C refer to different lifetimes. How can I have a single for<'a> that covers both generics?

Think: if you have Intermediary<'a> containing a &'a str, can you extract a &'static str from it? That's what you request the compiler.

I don’t think that’s what I’m doing/want. The lifetime of the &’a str should be determined by the caller of the closure, i.e. example. If example has let src = “foo”.to_string(); let source = Source { content: &src }; then the lifetime ‘a should be the lifetime of src. And let final = f(source); should have the same lifetime as src.

It seems you are out of luck in stable rust, the syntax of where clauses doesn't allow a for to cover multiple type bound items. You could do it with the unstable trait alias feature.

I’m a bit dumbfounded how trait aliases can solve this feature. Can you give an example or ideally how to solve the example above with this feature?

You can apply a for quantifier to multiple type bounds by using the unstable trait_alias feature, for example:
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait Intermediate<'a, F> = where 
    F: FnOnce(Source<'a>) -> Self,
    Self: Into<Final<'a>>;

fn example<F, C>(f: F)
where
    for<'a> C: Intermediate<'a, F>
{
    // implementation details
}

One of the type variables is picked as Self (here C) and the trait is named appropriately. You could also make all the type variables explicit and use a dummy for Self, but that may be confusing for the reader, see this answer.

Thanks your your response.
Calling your solution with
example(|ex: Source| {
Intermediary { content: ex.content }
});
gives me an error about needing to annotate the call, because C can't be inferred.
If I use
example(|ex| {
Intermediary { content: ex.content }
});
I get an error about missing a type for ex

It's not a full solution, just a possible step to put a for quantifier on a more complicated bound. I now tried to get it to work fully here, but I'm also lost.

The bound can actually be fully expressed by using a helper trait:
trait HelperTrait<'a>: FnOnce(Source<'a>) -> Self::Out {
    type Out;
}
impl<'a, A, Out> HelperTrait<'a> for A
where
    A: FnOnce(Source<'a>) -> Out,
{
    type Out = Out;
}

fn example<F>(f: F)
where
    for<'a> F: HelperTrait<'a, Out: Into<Final<'a>>>,
{
}

The problem is unfortunately not entirely solved because rust doesn't always handle higher ranked closures properly. This can be fixed either by not using closures or by forcing the closure to be higher ranked by passing it through an identity function with appropriate bounds (or possibly by using the higher-order-closure crate):
fn force_higher_ranked<F>(f: F) -> F
where
    F: for<'a> FnOnce(Source<'a>) -> Intermediary<'a>,
{
    f
}

fn call() {
    example(force_higher_ranked(|source: Source| Intermediary {
        content: source.content,
    }));
}

Playground
